# fabricjs group itext and rectangle within rectangle boundaries

Tags: fabricjs

Hi Is there some way that Itext and rectangle could be grouped and on clicking on the text, itext is editable with in the rectangle width. In case text is beyond the rectangle, it should wrap to the next line or font size is decreased.

Comment: Happy to help...  Can you provide some code or a work example?

Comment: Thanks tim here is the link. This is exactly what I am looking for in fabricjs
[link](http://dw.convertfiles.com/files/0425054001487482660/demo.mp4)

Comment: Got it...  How far did you get?  Can you share some code?

Comment: I am not getting any clue. If I go for iText, we can not fix the width. However textbox can be used but problem with textbox is if textbox is grouped with other object,  it can not be scaled vertically.